# What is the difference between Canvas#getWidth() and View#getWidth in Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use these two methods in my project, but two values sometimes equal, sometimes not.

```java
public class HintView extends LinearLayout {
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.getWidth();
        canvas.getWidth();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the source code for both `LinearLayout` and `Canvas`, you'd notice:

1. LinearLayout's `getWidth()` method is actually from `View.java`, a class LinearLayout extends:

```
     * Return the width of your view.
     *
     * @return The width of your view, in pixels.
     */
    @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout")
    public final int getWidth() {
        return mRight - mLeft;
    }
```

If you on the other hand check out the Canvas' method:

```
    /**
     * Returns the width of the current drawing layer
     *
     * @return the width of the current drawing layer
     */
    public int getWidth() {
        return nGetWidth(mNativeCanvasWrapper);
    }
```

The `n` prefix is Google's way to saying: this goes to native (c++) code.

The view and its canvas can and will be different if the view has paddings, margins, etc. (i don't recall of off the top of my head all the related properties) but remember that a Canvas is just a "surface" with some given dimensions, contained in a `View`.

All things on Screen on Android are one form of View or another. A view needs to measure, and ask its children (if a ViewGroup, which is also a View), and then, after all this is done, it can confidently start drawing (`onDraw(Canvas)`).